# Chimp test stopped working, throwing error: missing or invalid 'entry.level'

Tags: selenium, testing, webdriver, mocha.js, chimp.js

I'm trying to run tests (Chimp/), there were working yesterday and today they are not. Here is chimp configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  // - - - - CHIMP - - - -
  watch: false,
  watchWithPolling: false,
  sync: true,

  // - - - - WEBDRIVER-IO  - - - -
  webdriverio: {
    coloredLogs: true,
    logLevel: 'silent',
    screenshotPath: './tests/logs/screenshots',
    waitforTimeout: 20000,
    waitforInterval: 250
  },

  // - - - - MOCHA  - - - -
  mocha: true,
  mochaConfig: {
    timeout: 20000,
  },
  chai: true,
  // path: './tests/spec',
  path: './tests/spec/shop/configurator/products',
  format: 'dot',

 // - - - - SELENIUM  - - - -
  browser: 'chrome',
  platform: 'ANY',
  name: '',
  user: '',
  key: '',
  port: null,
  host: null,

  // - - - - METEOR  - - - -
  ddp: 'http://localhost:3000',
  serverExecuteTimeout: 20000,

  // - - - - PHANTOM  - - - -
  phantom_w: 1920,
  phantom_h: 1280
};
```

Here is the report output, before first test even starts it fails.

```
[chimp] Running...


  Configurator @watch
    1) "before all" hook


  0 passing (10s)
  1 failing

  1) Configurator @watch "before all" hook:
     Uncaught unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unknown error: missing or invalid 'entry.level'
```

When running in browserstack, it works. Here is browserstack configuration:

```
var browserstack = require('browserstack-local');
var bs_local = new browserstack.Local();
var bs_local_args = {/* ... */};

// starts the Local instance with the required arguments
bs_local.start(bs_local_args, function () {
    console.log("Started BrowserStackLocal");
});

module.exports = {
    // - - - - CHIMP - - - -
    watch: false,
    watchWithPolling: false,
    sync: true,

    // - - - - WEBDRIVER-IO  - - - -
    webdriverio: {
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
        coloredLogs: true,
        desiredCapabilities: {
            os: 'OS X',
            os_version: 'El Capitan',
            browser: 'Chrome',
            browser_version: '58.0',
            resolution: '1280x1024',
            project: 'project',
            build: 'build',
            'browserstack.local': true
        },
        logLevel: 'silent',
        screenshotPath: './tests/logs/screenshots',
        waitforTimeout: 50000,
        waitforInterval: 250
    },

    // - - - - MOCHA  - - - -
    mocha: true,
    mochaConfig: {
        timeout: 60001, 
    },
    chai: true,
    path: './tests/spec',
    format: 'dots',

    // - - - - Screenshots - - - -
    screenshotsOnError: true,
    screenshotPath: './tests/logs/screenshots',
    captureAllStepScreenshots: false,
    saveScreenshotsToDisk: true,
    saveScreenshotsToReport: false,

    // - - - - SELENIUM  - - - -
    name: 'project',
    browser: 'Chrome',
    user: '...',
    key: '...',
    host: 'hub.browserstack.com',
    port: 80,

    // - - - - METEOR  - - - -
    ddp: 'http://localhost:3000',
    serverExecuteTimeout: 30000,

    // - - - - PHANTOM  - - - -
    phantom_w: 1280,
    phantom_h: 1024
};
```

What I tried to fix it was to update chimp (0.50.2), reinstall node_modules, run it with firefox, nothing helps. I tried that in different environments (OS / Ubuntu 16.04) and result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Chimp hides a lot of the Selenium configurations from you. For example it downloads the driver binaries for you on install. However, your local environment is usually a bit more complex than just that. First thing that you should check is - do your browsers updated their versions without you noticing it. This actually tend to happen if you haven't lock your `browser-driver-chimp` versions. As far I can see you use for the cloud run:

```
 browser: 'Chrome',
 browser_version: '58.0',
```

and this seems to work. So it is a good practice to lock their versions explicitly (this includes disabling the browser updates). I also don't see significant changes in chimp itself at [0.50.2](https://github.com/xolvio/chimp/blob/master/HISTORY.md#0502).

One way to check the compatible driver-browser versions is to go through the current release notes of [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt). In case this still doesn't help - downgrade either driver or browser pairs till it works.
It looks like you need `ChromeDriver v2.31 (2017-07-21)` with that Chrome version, while chimp one is [pinned to 2.28](https://github.com/xolvio/chimp/blob/master/src/bin/default.js#L76).

Couple of times I had to play the guessing game myself till make it work again.